# Add language to Sublime 3.2.2

Tags: sublime-text, github

GPSS language support is provided at:

https://github.com/dseight/Sublime-GPSS-H

Questions:

1. Which directory destination should be selected for the github clone?
2. What Sublime steps are required to configure.GPS an .LIS files to be recognized as GPSS input / output files?